# Testflight install bricks my iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, testflight

Whenever I try to install my app over testflight my iPhone bricks and needs to be restored. Am I doing something drastically wrong?

To add to this, I created a blank storyboard app with one screen and a button that does nothing, I uploaded that to testflight and it installed fine.

I then went to deploy my real app the traditional way to my device and it crashed the device again... this is the 1st time it's done that. I am going to restore the device again and try and upload the app through testflight. There is definitely something odd between testflight and apps that are deployed locally. Am I able to deploy to the same device using testflight and traditional test deployment using xCode? Is there a known issue with this?

Comment: That's a horribly vague question and is very unlikely to net you any answers.

Comment: The problem is - that is all there is to it!! I am doing nothing other than installing testflight and trying to open my app before the iPhone bricks! What else should I add?! And why close a question related to app testing?!?! Seriously shoddy if you ask me!!!

Comment: why is this being closed and downvoted?!? It's an actual bloody question!! this site is going down the pan fast!

Comment: Because it's a question of poor quality, which you should be aware of yourself. How can anyone know what you're doing wrong when you provided no info about what you're doing at all. Did you try installing on a different device? If you don't have one available, does it work on the simulator? What do you mean by bricking a device? What can you see on the screen? Can you reset? Hard-reset?

Comment: I have said exactly what I am doing!! this is dumb and i'm deleting my account off the back of this.

Comment: @iwayneo It's already 2h and your account is still there! ;-) Don't be offended. Your question is vague. Try reformulating it. Step by step: what are you doing? There is no known issue with Testflight's deployment - after all that's all why Testflight exists. What do you mean by "it bricks my iPhone"? Can you reboot it? If yes, it's not bricked. My best bet is your "real" app is doing something it isn't supposed to do. Any Jailbreaks on your device? Which device? You see: you're lacking information here.

Comment: I have built an app that deploys using xcode/xamarin. I have tested on  both iPHone 4s and 5. It just bricks.

Comment: A simple "No this is not normal" - there is nothing special about my app so I have no idea what you want me to specify. I am taking it appart and reconstructing from scratch - this question and the responses were a total waste of time.

Comment: btw - it bricks so bad my iPhone 5 is now dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a missing appid in the xamarin settings.

I don't understand:

a: why testflight even allows you to upload an app that can cause such a huge FAIL
b: why the iphone has to brick just because there is a stupid appid missing!!!

update: bug reported with Xamarin: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4378/probable-bug-in-xamarin-studio-vs-plugin